# CSS for additional Menu Item in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a website: http://stoogle.staging.wpengine.com.

I want to add a 3rd level to the main menu, which is not a default feature for the theme which only supports a 2nd level.

I managed to get a 3rd level by changing the header.php file in the theme, by changing the depth attribute from 2 to 3:

```
<?php
if (has_nav_menu('main_navigation')) {
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'main_navigation',
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'main-nav list-unstyled',
        'link_before' => '<span>',
        'link_after' => '</span>',
        'items_wrap' => '<nav id="main-nav-wrapper"><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul></nav>',
        'depth' => 3,
        'walker' => new vw_main_menu_walker()
    ));
}
?>
```

The problem I have now is that the third level now just displays over the 2nd level, so I think I need to use CSS to move it out the way, but I am unsure of which CSS class has to be added/edited, and what CSS would need to be inputted.

I think after some playing around that the correct class is:

```
.main-nav .sub-menu-item .sub-menu-item {

}
```

So now need to know what CSS should be input to make it display correctly as one would normally expect from a menu.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I created a menu item called 1st level with second level children and one item having third level children. As one can see, it renders over the second level children, so you can't access them anymore, it should be displayed on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this and then play around

```
.sub-menu.menu-even.sub-sub-menu.menu-depth-2 {
    background: #fff000 !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the logic behind whats happening?
I'm still learning so, would like to know whats actually happening.

Comment: This is simple CSS path that I took using Web developer tool ( firebug ) on Firefox and Chrome while inspecting your page -> Menu -> submenu -> submenu ul html.

Then what we are doing is positioning this sub-sub-menu ul class to the aboslute and then move it 50% from left and give background color.

Comment: So I've just noticed an issue that its causing when its on the mobile version, the menu items are pushed off screen.
Any idea on a fix for that?
You can view it when you make the window size a a lot smaller.

Comment: You need to add media queries to make it compatible with responsive sizes.

Comment: Try adding this code, for example .. this is for767px width and less screen size small devices like mobile,etc.

`@media (max-width: 767px) {
.sub-menu.menu-even.sub-sub-menu.menu-depth-2 {
    position: relative !important;
}
}`

Comment: Yep, did the trick with a little bit extra added:
left: 0% !important;
Thanks again for all your help :)